# nested browsing context techniques?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe

I'm curious if anyone knows of any techniques to create a nested browsing context without using an iFrame? I was asked this, and immediately said, No, but now I'm second guessing myself - perhaps there are some clever hacks out there to load a 3rd party document inside a parent document?

I did a quick search and found some cheesy full screen scraping techniques (http://feross.org/html5-fullscreen-api-attack/) but I mean more placing a child document in a parent document without using an iFrame. I don't think this is possible but I'd like to double check :-)

Comment: I found a hack to include third party content without an `iframe`: `<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg" />` As there are so many ways of including content into a website – what is it you are trying to do?

Comment: I'm curious how people are getting around iFrame limitations as the only means of adding a nested context. Right, since an img is not restricted by cross-domain loading, I suppose you could just scrape all the content in a page and then load each dom element (text/img/*).